# IntelliJ Idea does'nt recognize Compatibility Library in ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, intellij-idea, dependencies, actionbarsherlock

I am using `IntelliJ Idea CE` (which is incredible) and have included `ActionBar Sherlock` as Library and added it as dependency in my Module (term used in IntelliJ).

ActionBar Sherlock uses `android-support-v4.jar` and therefore it is not supposed to added as a dependency in my module(app).

In case I add `android-support-v4.jar` as a dependency in my module I get an error

> UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:

and when I remove it IDE don't recognize the classes in compatibility package and at times it compile the module at times it gives error.

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `android-support-v4.jar` library is already included in ActionBar Sherlock module, just click on the **Export** checkbox in the [module dependencies configuration](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html) on the left of the library name. This will make the library available for your main application.

Comment: If I have a main project that need android-support-v4 and other 3 library project that need it (and they actually have it included in the build-path) what have I to do? I check the export in all projects?